# Grafana Docker container will not launch on Fargate via Terraform, issue with mounted file storage

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, terraform, aws-fargate

My Grafana container will not launch on fargate via Terraform, as there is an issue with mounted file storage. The logs display three entries:

- You may have issues with file permissions, more information here: http://docs.grafana.org/installation/docker/#migrate-to-v51-or-later
- GF_PATHS_DATA='/var/lib/grafana' is not writable.
- mkdir: can't create directory '/var/lib/grafana/plugins': Permission denied

My task role assigned to the task definition does have full EFS access.

I very new to AWS and Terraform, so I am having trouble understanding what the Grafana documentation is suggesting. I've added a "user" field in the task definition and set it to 472 but I still have the same errors. Thank you so much for reading my issue.

```
resource "aws_ecs_task_definition" "grafana" {
  family                   = "grafana"
  requires_compatibilities = ["FARGATE"]
  network_mode             = "awsvpc"
  cpu                      = "512"
  memory                   = "1024"
  task_role_arn = "arn:aws:iam::692869463706:role/grafanaTaskRole"
  execution_role_arn = "arn:aws:iam::692869463706:role/ecsTaskExecutionRole"

  container_definitions = <<DEFINITION
[
  {
      "memory": 512,
      "cpu": 256,
      "portMappings": [
          {
              "hostPort": 3000,
              "containerPort": 3000,
              "protocol": "tcp"
          }
      ],
      "logConfiguration": {
                "logDriver": "awslogs",
                "options": {
                    "awslogs-create-group": "true",
                    "awslogs-group": "ecs-grafana",
                    "awslogs-region": "us-east-1",
                    "awslogs-stream-prefix": "grafana-task"
                }
            },
      "essential": true,
      "mountPoints": [
          {
              "containerPath": "/var/lib/grafana",
              "sourceVolume": "efs-html",
              "readOnly": null
          }
      ],
      "name": "grafana",
      "image": "grafana/grafana:latest",
      "user": "472"
  }
]
DEFINITION

  volume {
    name = "efs-html"
    efs_volume_configuration {
      file_system_id          = aws_efs_file_system.myfilesystem.id
      root_directory          = "/grafana"
      transit_encryption      = "ENABLED"
      transit_encryption_port = 2999

      authorization_config {
        access_point_id = aws_efs_access_point.test.id
        iam             = "ENABLED"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Does the task role have full EFS access, or full EFS Client access? Those are two different things. One allows things like creating EFS volumes, the other allows access to the contents of EFS volumes. If the IAM role has full EFS client access, then you may need to fix the unix permissions of the `/grafana` folder in the EFS volume to allow your process to create a subfolder in there.

Comment: My task role does have full client access. I am looking into the POSIX file settings now, thank you for the reply!

Comment: @MarkB That totally solved my issue, thank you so much! I wish I could buy you a door dash gift card or something, you seriously saved my sanity! Haha